# Engine light on after driving through deep water

Tags: mercedes-benz

Turned a corner and hit a rather deep puddle, was sure I wouldn’t make it through, but I did. A car ahead of me had just been towed out after it completely died in the water (so I’m hoping I’ve been lucky) Drove home, 5 mins of a journey with no problems, engine sounded fine etc. Just been out to check car,  turned over fine but there’s now an engine warning light on. My mechanic is a good 20 mins journey away and I’m concerned about driving there with it. There was a fairly high bow wave the came over the bonnet. Do I leave it to dry out for a few days or arrange for it to be towed? Advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it may or may not be ok - does the light that is on have a specific symbol? Oil for example...

As it continued to drive then most items should be ok , but the air filter may need replacing for example and checking the oil level in engine and gearbox also needs to be done.

This has been asked and answered before, see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/52046/10976

Comment: Many thanks, on full inspection this morning, we’ve removed about a litre of water from the air filter box, replacing air filter, as my son put code reader on and it identified a problem with air/fuel. So it’s a fingers crossed at moe. Will follow the suggestions in your link.

Comment: So well done - once you have removed that water and fitted the new filter, it may be worth running it then clearing the codes and running it again. That code may be due to the old air filter being waterlogged...

Comment: Given it a good run and absolutely fine. We’d cleared the error code before fitting new air filter and it’s not reappeared. So looking like I had a very lucky escape. Thx for the help, much appreciated!